# How to loop over radiobuttons Itemrenderers in datagrid in Flex

Tags: datagrid, flex4, radio-button

Hello can someone help on looping on radiobuttons item renderers in a Flex MX Datagrid?

My datagrid code is as follows:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="20" headerText="isDefault" dataField="IS_DEFAULT">
                            <mx:itemRenderer>
                                <fx:Component>
                                    <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left">
                                        <fx:Script>
                                            <![CDATA[
                                                import mx.controls.Alert;
                                                import mx.controls.listClasses.ListData;


                                                protected function chk1_changeHandler(event:Event):void
                                                {

                                                } 

                                            ]]>
                                        </fx:Script>
                                        <mx:RadioButton id="chk1" selected="{data.IS_DEFAULT == 'N' ? false : true}"
                                                        groupName="{outerDocument.rbg11}" change="chk1_changeHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                                            </mx:HBox>
                                </fx:Component>
                            </mx:itemRenderer>
                        </mx:DataGridColumn>



Thanks for helping.
```

Answer (score 0):

why not bind the state of the checkbox item inline-renderers with the data grid's dataprovider?  is there some other sort of functionality you're specifically trying to access via each checkbox control? if not, I'd recommend just adding a selected/not-selected property to whatever your dataprovider is and bind that to the "selected" property for the inline checkbox renderer like this:

```
<mx:RadioButton id="chk1" selected="{data.selected_property}"
                                    groupName="{outerDocument.rbg11}" change="chk1_changeHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

this way if you want loop over the "state" of each and every checkbox in the datagrid control, you can do it at the data provider level.  your chk1_changeHandler() would just toggle that selected/not-selected value:

```
protected function chk1_changeHandler(event:Event):void{
    if(data.selected_property == true){
        data.selected_property = false;
    }else{
        data.selected_property = true;
    }
}
```

I'd read up on some subtle flex 3 binding nuances here if you're dead set on mx (~3.x) rather than 4.6: [About Binding](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html)